# How do I take 1000 items from a dynamic table, edit and then update them?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm just getting started with MongoDB, but loving it so far.

Now I need to run through a large table of data and process the records in batches, marking them as processed assuming everything went well.

I can collect the data like this:

```
        var Client = new MongoClient();
        var DB = Client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = DB.GetCollection<Sample>("sample");
        var filter = Builders<Sample>.Filter.Eq(b => b.NeedsProcessing, true);
        var items = collection.Find(filter).Limit(1000);
```

I run through the items in the collection and assuming all is well I need to mark the items as processed. Is there a way to clear the NeedsProcessing flag for all of these items short of an individual update query for each one based on id? I assume I can't just update the first 1000 again, as the list may have changed by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one way to do it:

```
            var update = Builders<Datablob>.Update.Set(b => b.NeedsUploading, false);
            var ids = itemsEn.AsQueryable().Select(i => i.ID);
            var updateFilter = Builders<Datablob>.Filter.In(i => i.ID, ids);

            collection.UpdateMany(updateFilter, update);
```

Still feels a bit nasty, though. Is there a built in way of doing this?

Comment: I can't think of anything better, I'm going to call this an answer for now.